# AngularJS nested function call in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I have set up a simple fiddle that by pressing enter in textbox should show alert. It does work fine in latest IE and Chrome but does not work in Firefox: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prztey7m/2/)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl as form">
    <input type="text" ng-keypress="form.ProcessSearchKeyPress($event)">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

// controller
app.controller('appCtrl', function () {

    this.Search = function ()
    {
        alert('search');
    };

    this.ProcessSearchKeyPress = function (event)
    {
        if (event.charCode == 13)
        {
            this.Search();
        }
    };

});
```

It looks like the function Search defined in controller is never called in case of Firefox. Have I missed something or its a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest wrapping your textbox in a form and using ng-submit event to handle search. The browser already knows how to handle the enter key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`charCode` property is not standard and deprecated. Use cross browser `keyCode` which will work in Firefox too:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    this.Search();
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/prztey7m/3/

Comment: This works and probably will continue to work for some time, but keyCode is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.keyCode

Comment: @doogabides Yep, in future `event.key` should be used and for transition probably `event.key || event.keyCode`.